# How to restart FastCGI process from source?

Tags: fastcgi, php, ini

I have Plesk 12, and I installed another version of PHP using this guide. I switched a specific domain to use this version. So in the hosting settings, it says

```
PHP support (Run PHP as [FastCGI application], PHP version 5.3.1
```

Now, I needed to edit the php.ini file to turn on short tags (eww gross I know), but I can't turn them on. When I run service apache2 restart it doesn't restart FastCGI. It is installed at `/usr/local/php531-cgi`

```
ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1204 Mar 18 22:47 pear.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69623 Mar 18 23:36 php.ini
```

I tried restarting the entire server, setting ini_set('short_open_tag',true);, and the commands `service php5-fpm restart` / `service php-fpm restart`

But the results are the same, `short_open_tag   Off`

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` for the right `php.ini` file to edit. Alternatively, see the manual on [.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files.

Comment: Hey that was it! I was using `/usr/local/php531-cgi/etc/php.ini`. The one I needed to use was in `/var/www/vhosts/system/[domainname.com]/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I followed @mario's advice, and checked phpinfo(). I was using the wrong php.ini file. I was using `/usr/local/php531-cgi/etc/php.ini`. The one I needed to use was in `/var/www/vhosts/system/[domainname.com]/php.ini`

I didnt even need to restart anything. Thanks Mario!

Answer (score 0):

a quick command to see which php.ini file you're using

```
php -i | grep /php.ini
```